# How do I get JUnit4 annotations to work in Spring2.5?

Tags: hibernate, spring, junit4

I've been trying to create a JUnit test for my DAO that uses Hibernate and is linked to the database via Spring in my applicationContext.xml file.

The error only occurs when adding:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

Otherwise I get a null pointer exception to the partDao, which is expected because it isn't linking.

Normally I'd just say scrap it and continue developing without JUnit tests, but I would prefer to start using it in my projects.

Here is the error:

```
Testsuite: SpecBuilder.webapp.dao.PartDaoTest
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier.testAborted(Lorg/junit/runner/Description;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:146)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter.run(JUnit4TestAdapter.java:39)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run(JUnitTestRunner.java:515)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.launch(JUnitTestRunner.java:1031)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.main(JUnitTestRunner.java:888)
Test SpecBuilder.webapp.dao.PartDaoTest FAILED (crashed)
/home/zclark/Projects/SpecBuilder/nbproject/build-impl.xml:798: Some tests failed; see details above.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Here is my test class:

```
package SpecBuilder.webapp.dao;

import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations="{applicationContext.xml}")
public class PartDaoTest {

    @Autowired
    PartDao partDao;

    public PartDaoTest() {}

    @Test
    public void autowireTest() {
        assertNotNull(partDao);
    }
}
```

And here is my applicationContext:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
      p:location="/WEB-INF/specbuilder.properties"/>

    <bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
      p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
      p:url="${jdbc.url}"
      p:username="${jdbc.username}"
      p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

    <bean id="partDao" class="SpecBuilder.webapp.dao.PartDao">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>SpecBuilder.webapp.model.Part</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you need JUnit 4.3 or 4.4 to work with Spring 2.5.

Comment: Thank you.  Was too blind to look at that.  Did some more snooping, https://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-5145 describes the exact cause of the incompatibility